# how to customize pos receipt in pos_restaurant module?

Tags: jquery, odoo, odoo-10, point-of-sale

There are two reports,"BillReceipt" & "PosTicket". One in POS_Restaurant and the second in point_of_sale module. BillReceipt works with POSbox connected and Posticket works without POSbox.
I inherited PosTicket and customized it and it works fine but when i connect the POSbox the BillReceipt comes on.

addons/point_of_sale/static/src/xml/pos.xml , PosTicket.

addons/pos_restaurant/static/src/xml/printbill.xml, BillReceipt

I want to customize the receipt in the POS Restaurant module by inheriting the template with t-name="BillReceipt".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">

<t t-name="BillReceipt">
    <receipt align='center' width='40' value-thousands-separator='' >
        <t t-if='receipt.company.logo'>
            <img t-att-src='receipt.company.logo' />
            <br/>
        </t>
        <t t-if='!receipt.company.logo'>
            <h1><t t-esc='receipt.company.name' /></h1>
            <br/>
        </t>
        <div font='b'>
            <t t-if='receipt.shop.name'>
                <div><t t-esc='receipt.shop.name' /></div>
            </t>
            <t t-if='receipt.company.contact_address'>
                <div><t t-esc='receipt.company.contact_address' /></div>
            </t>
            <t t-if='receipt.company.phone'>
                <div>Tel:<t t-esc='receipt.company.phone' /></div>
            </t>
            <t t-if='receipt.company.vat'>
                <div>VAT:<t t-esc='receipt.company.vat' /></div>
            </t>
            <t t-if='receipt.company.email'>
                <div><t t-esc='receipt.company.email' /></div>
            </t>
            <t t-if='receipt.company.website'>
                <div><t t-esc='receipt.company.website' /></div>
            </t>
            <t t-if='receipt.header'>
                <div><t t-esc='receipt.header' /></div>
            </t>
            <t t-if='receipt.cashier'>
                <div class='cashier'>
                    <div>--------------------------------</div>
                    <div>Served by <t t-esc='receipt.cashier' /></div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </div>
        <br /><br />

        <!-- Orderlines -->

        <div line-ratio='0.6'>
            <t t-foreach='receipt.orderlines' t-as='line'>
                <t t-set='simple' t-value='line.discount === 0 and line.unit_name === "Unit(s)" and line.quantity === 1' />
                <t t-if='simple'>
                    <line>
                        <left><t t-esc='line.product_name' /></left>
                        <right><value><t t-esc='line.price_display' /></value></right>
                    </line>
                </t>
                <t t-if='!simple'>
                    <line><left><t t-esc='line.product_name' /></left></line>
                    <t t-if='line.discount !== 0'>
                        <line indent='1'><left>Discount: <t t-esc='line.discount' />%</left></line>
                    </t>
                    <line indent='1'>
                        <left>
                            <value value-decimals='3' value-autoint='on'>
                                <t t-esc='line.quantity' />
                            </value>
                            <t t-if='line.unit_name !== "Unit(s)"'>
                                <t t-esc='line.unit_name' /> 
                            </t>
                            x 
                            <value value-decimals='2'>
                                <t t-esc='line.price' />
                            </value>
                        </left>
                        <right>
                            <value><t t-esc='line.price_display' /></value>
                        </right>
                    </line>
                </t>
            </t>
        </div>

        <!-- Subtotal -->
        <t t-set='taxincluded' t-value='Math.abs(receipt.subtotal - receipt.total_with_tax) &lt;= 0.000001' />
        <t t-if='!taxincluded'>
            <line><right>--------</right></line>
            <line><left>Subtotal</left><right> <value><t t-esc="receipt.subtotal" /></value></right></line>
            <t t-foreach='receipt.tax_details' t-as='tax'>
                <line>
                    <left><t t-esc='tax.name' /></left>
                    <right><value><t t-esc='tax.amount' /></value></right>
                </line>
            </t>
        </t>

        <!-- Total -->

        <line><right>--------</right></line>
        <line size='double-height'>
            <left><pre>        TOTAL</pre></left>
            <right><value><t t-esc='receipt.total_with_tax' /></value></right>
        </line>
        <br/><br/>

        <!-- Extra Payment Info -->

        <t t-if='receipt.total_discount'>
            <line>
                <left>Discounts</left>
                <right><value><t t-esc='receipt.total_discount'/></value></right>
            </line>
        </t>
        <t t-if='taxincluded'>
            <t t-foreach='receipt.tax_details' t-as='tax'>
                <line>
                    <left><t t-esc='tax.name' /></left>
                    <right><value><t t-esc='tax.amount' /></value></right>
                </line>
            </t>
        </t>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <t t-if='receipt.footer_xml'>
            <t t-raw='receipt.footer_xml' />
        </t>

        <t t-if='!receipt.footer_xml and receipt.footer'>
            <br/>
            <t t-esc='receipt.footer' />
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </t>

        <br/>
        <div font='b'>
            <div><t t-esc='receipt.name' /></div>
            <div><t t-esc='receipt.date.localestring' /></div>
        </div>

    </receipt>
</t>

</templates>
```

I intend to completely replace the current receipt format with the one that i already made in the POS module which comes right after clicking the payment button.
And also,is it possible to make that receipt work with POSbox connected?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inherit that Qweb template report then you can do by following way:

```
<t t-extend="BillReceipt">
    <t t-jquery='place_where_you_want_to_do_chnage' t-operation='differet_operations'>
    </t>
</t>
```

Here you can use different `t-jquery` properties and also pass value to field `t-operation` likewise your requirment. You can get more idea from this link : [t-jquery document](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/what-is-t-jquery-in-qweb-72802)

Now, if you want to override the template then you just need to call same template with same id in your custom module. By that way template has been override.

Comment: how can i do that? to override the template.

Comment: this is how i inherited the template   <templates id="pos_restaurant.template" xml:space="preserve">


<t t-extend="BillReceipt">
 <t t-jquery='receipt' t-operation='replace'>

Comment: To override the template you need to use same id of base template i.e. `<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
<t t-name="BillReceipt">
//custom code
</t>`

This is how you can override base template into your custom module.

Comment: the table tag doesnt seem to work in this template, why is that?

Comment: There is no any `<table>` tag in base template. If you want to add then you can add that too.

Comment: is jasper reporting necessary for making customizations in this template?

Comment: I don't have any idea related to ' jasper reporting'